# Utility type to apply dependency injection to a given type?

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, typescript-generics

All over my JS code, there are a lot of functions that are injected an object (a database connection, specifically).  They all follow the pattern:

```
const myFunction = (dbConnection) => async (functionArguments) => { //body of the function}
```

Since we're now moving to Typescript, I would like to create types for all the function signatures without mentioning the injection, like so:

```
type FirstFunctionType = (request: FirstFunctionRequest) => Promise<FirstFunctionReturnType>;

type SecondFunctionType = (request: SecondFunctionRequest) => Promise<SecondFunctionReturnType>;
```

And then create an utility type that handles the injection:

```
type InjectConnection<T> = (connection: Pool) => T;
```

So that my first function would end up being of type `InjectConnection<FirstFunctionType>`, and after the injection is done I can assign the result to `FirstFunctionType`.

However, this method doesn't seem to be working, as `InjectConnection` is not being detected as a type (I'm getting an error `'Cannot find name 'InjectConnection'.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you using `InjectConnection<FirstFunctionType>` ?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgJwM7BgVwHYGNhwPYYBKEAjmhClALxQDeUAjAFyNQC+A3AFCiRQDKELAQAm6bLgLEyFYNTpQATC0XtuvaPGSpMOfEQjA0CDABVw0GvQDMLa2p4WBQ0eL1TDxs06tQALCx+DhpQAAp4eAA28vTCGBhCwCwAFACU1AB8YQh4ALZwSBAAPLRsWZxcjnxaKG6S3nw0yVxQUAik5CgsNToS+tKdwFzpVFmhOfmFRT11-Z4m5pAZ3FXQgnFiuvWLllDNre0yXc4bsx5HQyNjEwXF665bc0YLFsuVIQCSGABWiQDCBAS7gwRVMWSacSB9RY4SiVygphWcUoYDgADMWF9fjgAfFEvoii1YIhao8CDsuOCoJD8QRMlAAIZIEDYNodWT05K0Im2KDWLhsVJIgiUDHE7RnBq7VFornUwGJFhMllYPbwrmC9hCrhAA

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks for the example. It seems that my version isn't working because my Pool type is being imported from an external module (import { Pool } from 'pg';). I'm assuming it's a problem of scopes, but I don't know how to fix it. Any idea?

Comment: @kace91 that shouldn't matter at all unless you are transitively referencing different versions of `pg` or something. Can you provide an example that reproduces the issue?